# How can I group tasks with asyncio in Python to execute them combined serially and concurrently?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have the following function:

```
async def pre_processing_list_sic_codes(
        self,
        start_date: datetime,
        final_date: datetime,
        sic_codes: List[str]
        ) -> Any:
        batch_length = 80
        batches = [sic_codes[i : i + batch_length] for i in range(0, len(sic_codes), batch_length)]
        task = []
        for batch in batches:
            task.append(
                self.processing(
                    sic_codes=batch,
                    start_date=start_date,
                    final_date=final_date,
                )
            )
        # here
```

Then, the task list contains all the tasks that need to be executed. What I normally do is simply:

```
await gather(*task)
```

However, these tasks involve operations with a database and since there are so many threads, I reach the connection limit. My idea is to group these tasks (for example 3 or 4) so that the tasks are executed serially within the group and at the same time the groups are executed asynchronously. How can I implement it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear from your question to me, however I have assumed that you are sending batches of SIC codes to the db to start with, and these batches you would like to run concurrently.

There are several ways to approach this which obviously might change depending where my assumptions are incorrect. I use this approach all the time, to batch up groups of asynchronous processing. Below is a quick attempt at orchestrating the processing of your batches while not exceed some db_concurrency threshold.

```py
import datetime
import asyncio
from typing import Any, List

SIC_CODES = ["1110","1120","1130","1140","1150","1160","1190","1210","1220","1230","1240","1250","1260","1270","1280","1290","1300","1410","1420","1430","1440","1450","1460","1470","1490","1500","1610","1621","1629","1630","1640","1700","2100","2200","2300","2400","3110","3120","3210","3220","5101","5102","5200","6100","6200","7100","7210","7290","8110","8120","8910","8920","8930","8990","9100","9900","10110","10120","10130","10200","10310","10320","10390","10410","10420","10511","10512","10519","10520","10611","10612","10620","10710","10720","10730","10810","10821","10822","10831","10832","10840","10850","10860","10890","10910","10920","11010","11020","11030","11040","11050","11060","11070","12000","13100","13200","13300","13910","13921","13922","13923","13931","13939","13940","13950","13960","13990","14110","14120","14131","14132","14141","14142","14190","14200","14310","14390","15110","15120","15200","16100","16210","16220","16230","16240","16290","17110","17120","17211","17219","17220","17230","17240","17290","18110","18121","18129","18130","18140","18201","18202","18203","19100","19201","19209","20110","20120","20130","20140","20150","20160","20170","20200","20301","20302","20411","20412","20420","20510","20520","20530","20590","20600","21100","21200","22110","22190","22210","22220","22230","22290","23110","23120","23130","23140","23190","23200","23310","23320","23410","23420","23430","23440","23490","23510","23520","23610","23620","23630","23640","23650","23690","23700","23910","23990","24100","24200","24310","24320","24330","24340","24410","24420","24430","24440","24450","24460","24510","24520","24530","24540","25110","25120","25210","25290","25300","25400","25500","25610","25620","25710","25720","25730","25910","25920","25930","25940","25990","26110","26120","26200","26301","26309","26400","26511","26512","26513","26514","26520","26600","26701","26702","26800","27110","27120","27200","27310","27320","27330","27400","27510","27520","27900","28110","28120","28131","28132","28140","28150","28210","28220","28230","28240","28250","28290","28301","28302","28410","28490","28910","28921","28922","28923","28930","28940","28950","28960","28990","29100","29201","29202","29203","29310","29320","30110","30120","30200","30300","30400","30910","30920","30990","31010","31020","31030","31090","32110","32120","32130","32200","32300","32401","32409","32500","32910","32990","33110","33120","33130","33140","33150","33160","33170","33190","33200","35110","35120","35130","35140","35210","35220","35230","35300","36000","37000","38110","38120","38210","38220","38310","38320","39000","41100","41201","41202","42110","42120","42130","42210","42220","42910","42990","43110","43120","43130","43210","43220","43290","43310","43320","43330","43341","43342","43390","43910","43991","43999","45111","45112","45190","45200","45310","45320","45400","46110","46120","46130","46140","46150","46160","46170","46180","46190","46210","46220","46230","46240","46310","46320","46330","46341","46342","46350","46360","46370","46380","46390","46410","46420","46431","46439","46440","46450","46460","46470","46480","46491","46499","46510","46520","46610","46620","46630","46640","46650","46660","46690","46711","46719","46720","46730","46740","46750","46760","46770","46900","47110","47190","47210","47220","47230","47240","47250","47260","47290","47300","47410","47421","47429","47430","47510","47520","47530","47540","47591","47599","47610","47620","47630","47640","47650","47710","47721","47722","47730","47741","47749","47750","47760","47770","47781","47782","47789","47791","47799","47810","47820","47890","47910","47990","49100","49200","49311","49319","49320","49390","49410","49420","49500","50100","50200","50300","50400","51101","51102","51210","51220","52101","52102","52103","52211","52212","52213","52219","52220","52230","52241","52242","52243","52290","53100","53201","53202","55100","55201","55202","55209","55300","55900","56101","56102","56103","56210","56290","56301","56302","58110","58120","58130","58141","58142","58190","58210","58290","59111","59112","59113","59120","59131","59132","59133","59140","59200","60100","60200","61100","61200","61300","61900","62011","62012","62020","62030","62090","63110","63120","63910","63990","64110","64191","64192","64201","64202","64203","64204","64205","64209","64301","64302","64303","64304","64305","64306","64910","64921","64922","64929","64991","64992","64999","65110","65120","65201","65202","65300","66110","66120","66190","66210","66220","66290","66300","68100","68201","68202","68209","68310","68320","69101","69102","69109","69201","69202","69203","70100","70210","70221","70229","71111","71112","71121","71122","71129","71200","72110","72190","72200","73110","73120","73200","74100","74201","74202","74203","74209","74300","74901","74902","74909","74990","75000","77110","77120","77210","77220","77291","77299","77310","77320","77330","77341","77342","77351","77352","77390","77400","78101","78109","78200","78300","79110","79120","79901","79909","80100","80200","80300","81100","81210","81221","81222","81223","81229","81291","81299","81300","82110","82190","82200","82301","82302","82911","82912","82920","82990","84110","84120","84130","84210","84220","84230","84240","84250","84300","85100","85200","85310","85320","85410","85421","85422","85510","85520","85530","85590","85600","86101","86102","86210","86220","86230","86900","87100","87200","87300","87900","88100","88910","88990","90010","90020","90030","90040","91011","91012","91020","91030","91040","92000","93110","93120","93130","93191","93199","93210","93290","94110","94120","94200","94910","94920","94990","95110","95120","95210","95220","95230","95240","95250","95290","96010","96020","96030","96040","96090","97000","98000","98100","98200","99000","99999"]

sic_code_count = 0


async def processing(sic_codes: List[str], start_date: datetime, final_date: datetime) -> Any:
    """ Database processing goes here
    """
    global sic_code_count
    sic_code_count += len(sic_codes)


async def pre_processing_list_sic_codes(
        start_date: datetime,
        final_date: datetime,
        sic_codes: List[str]
) -> Any:
    db_concurrency = 3
    batch_length = 80
    batches = [sic_codes[i: i + batch_length] for i in range(0, len(sic_codes), batch_length)]
    batch_jobs = []
    while len(batches) > 0:
        batch_jobs.append(batches.pop(0))
        if len(batch_jobs) == db_concurrency or len(batches) == 0:
            tasks = [
                asyncio.create_task(processing(
                    sic_codes=job,
                    start_date=start_date,
                    final_date=final_date)) for job in batch_jobs
            ]
            await asyncio.wait(tasks)
            batch_jobs = []


async def main():
    await pre_processing_list_sic_codes(
        start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        final_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 1),
        sic_codes=SIC_CODES,
    )
    print(f"Total SIC Codes: {len(SIC_CODES)}")
    print(f"Processed SIC Codes: {sic_code_count}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: It is a good implementation and I think it is effective. For my part, I finally ended up using Semaphores from Asyncio, I don't know if you already know them but I'm sharing the link to the documentation because I honestly didn't know these techniques and I found them too useful: https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/asyncio-sync.html

Comment: Thank's for pointing that out Diego. I use conditional's, but reading the docs, it looks like Barriers could achieve something similar to the solution discussed here. As a side note are reading those docs, I avoid using locking in async flows, as it feels like an anti pattern.